# deploy spring war tomcat Context initialization failed

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

i'm working in spring app that works fine in eclipse with the tomcat server, but when i generate the war file and i put it in the webapps folder then i start the server via startup.bat (im using windows) the app not deployed and i got the following error :

```
Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1c28abf:
```

folowed by the name of all my beans , the i got the following message :

```
ERROR o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
Error creating bean with name 'configurer' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-business.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'properties' while setting bean property 'properties';
```

do you have any idea why the app works fine (the spring context initilazed correctly) when i start it in eclipse and not works when i deploy the war manually in tomcat.

this is the config of my context using server.xml

```
<Logger className="org.apache.catalina.logger.SystemOutLogger" timestamp="true" verbosity="4"/>
<Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" maxTotal="10" maxIdle="3" maxWaitMillis="10000" name="jdbc/AppDB" 
password="mypassword" type="javax.sql.DataSource" url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@ 127.0.0.1:20300:MYSID" username="mypassword"/>

</Context>
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Problem is here: ` Cannot resolve reference to bean 'properties'`

Comment: Can you share , where properties bean configured in spring configuration file ?

Comment: Hi @RameshFadatare thank you for your time , this the bean declaration     <bean id="configurer"  class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="properties" ref="properties" />
        <property name="systemPropertiesModeName"  value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE" />
    </bean>

Comment: Do you configured bean in your configuration file like <bean id="properties" class = "" /> ?

Comment: hi @FranMontero but why this bean is initilazed correctly when i start the in eclipse and not works when i deploy the war manually

Comment: @RameshFadatare yes 
 <bean id="properties" class="org.springmodules.commons.configuration.CommonsConfigurationFactoryBean">
        <property name="configurations">
            <bean id="externalConfiguration"class="org.apache.commons.configuration.PropertiesConfiguration">
                <constructor-arg type="java.net.URL"value="classpath:/activ.properties"/>
                <property name="reloadingStrategy"ref="managedConfiguration"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
       <property name="locations"value="classpath:activ.properties"/>
    </bean>

Comment: unfortunately i'm not the developper who create this beans...

Comment: @James have you checked that activ.properties is packaged inside the war?

Comment: @FranMontero thank you for your time , the properties file doesn't exist in the war file.